# Play 2 - inMemoryDatabase() precision for FakeApplication

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, in-memory-database

In order to launch a test based on a fake application using memory database, Play Framework 2 promotes doing this way:

```
FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())
```

Is it a necessity to precise `additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase()` if the `application.conf` already declares a memory database (h2) dedicated for tests?

I guess this additional configuration forces to redeclare a clean memory database for each fake application, rather than using the same for all suite test. Thus involving a full isolation for each one and avoid us to redefine `setUp()` and `tearDown()` method to manage it.

What is useful for?

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is simply an helper.